# Integer Linear Combinations | Books on Table

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm learning a course from Coursera related to Discrete Mathematics, I come across with this question about Integer Linear Combinations and I really need an explanation and how can I show this problem. Thanks for any help:

*There are some books on the table. If you group them by 3, you get some number of full groups and 2 books remain; if you group them by 4, you get some number of full groups and 3 books remain; if you group them by 5, you get some number of full groups and 4 books remain. What is the number of books on the table, if it is less than 100?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

This is a problem of simultaneous congruences: find the integer $0\le x <100$ such that
\begin{cases}
x\equiv 2\mod 3, \\x\equiv 3\mod 4,\\ x\equiv 5\mod 5.
\end{cases}
Such a system is solved in pairs: beginning with the first two, you'll obtain a solution $x\equiv k\mod 12$, and grouping it with the last congruence, you'll have a final (general) solution $x\equiv l\mod 60$.

To solve a system of two linear congruences with coprime moduli:
\begin{cases}
x\equiv \alpha\mod a,\\ x\equiv\beta\mod b,
\end{cases}
you have to use the inverse isomorphism of the *Chinese remainder theorem*. If $ua+vby=1\enspace (u,v\in \mathbf Z)$ is a Bézout's relation between the moduli, the solution to the system of congruences is
$$x\equiv \beta ua+\alpha vb\mod ab.$$